# How to set an ImageView to always follow another ImageView in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview

I have ImageViews of an arm and a hand. I'd like to make the hand a child of the arm so that if the arm pivots at the elbow, the hand stays at the wrist and can also be pivoted separately at the wrist.

I've been able to set the position of the hand relative to the elbow when both are static using the following method:

```
private void positionHand(){
    int left = arm.getLeft();
    int top = arm.getTop();
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200,200);
    params.setMargins(left + 600, top+100, 0, 0);
    hand.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

This method gets the top left corner of the arm and then sets the hand relative to that corner ("left + 600" and "top + 100"). However, if I animate the arm:

```
 arm.animate().rotationBy(95).setDuration(2000);
```

The hand remains at the same position while the arm rotates away. How can I set the position of the hand so that it always follows the arm?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was to create a nested RelativeLayout in the XML and to put my ImageViews inside that Layout. Then, I could have the entire layout rotate and the images would rotate along, remaining stationary relative to each other. I can also have the images rotate on their own axes while spinning with the layout.